# Qt: What is the best approach to update the widgets in the GUI?

Tags: c++, qt

I used a QTimer to control when should I update my widgets.
Many people suggested to do:

```
void uavTabGroup::updateMgr()
{

    setUpdatesEnabled(false);
    for (updateCtr = 0; updateCtr < max_num; updateCtr++)
    {
        if (infoView[updateCtr] != NULL)// its a child widget to the current widget
        {
            infoView[updateCtr]->updateDisplay();
        }
    }
    setUpdatesEnabled(true);
}
```

But I found that to update the widgets sequentially give me better results:

```
void uavTabGroup::updateMgr()
    {
        if (updateCtr >= max_num)
            updateCtr = 0;

        if (infoView[updateCtr] != NULL)
        {
            infoView[updateCtr]->updateDisplay();
        }

        updateCtr++;
    }
```

In this case the `updateMgr()` is called at higher frequency, but for each time only one of its child widget is updated.
What is the best way?

Comment: I would use signals and slots for this. emit the signal `updateDisplay()` that all your widgets are connected to their slot `updateDisplay()`.

Comment: I have done that before, but is there any advantage in that way in terms of efficiency (not the easy of writing code)?

Comment: I have not benchmarked either method so I can not really say.